# Can you search groups of text using for x in python?

Tags: python, loops, text

So I am working on a small program that would scan a line of compressed text (Think Variable 1 would be shortened to V1, Variable 2 would be shortened to V2, and things like Start would be shortened to S). I am attempting to have my program scan through this text using for x... loops. My apologies for all the comments in advance, feel free to modify them! Anyways, this is my code:

```
Text = "S V1XV2E" # The code is incomplete to search all the text, but that's a me problem

I = 0 # Create index for later

for x in Text: # Look through all text
    I = I + 1 # Increase index for every letter searched
    if x == Text[:I]: # Text starts at 0, Text[:I] = 0th char always = S 
        if x == "S": # Therefore this is always correct unless the sample changes
            print("Start")
            I = 1 # Set "I" to 1 to skip over the space
    if x == Text[I:I+2]: # Here the idea is since "I" is set to 1, it will search the text from the 1st to 3rd char, so "V1"
        if x == "V1": # "x" is only 1 character, so this always fails
            print("Var 1")
```

The only problem is that "x" can only see one character at a time in this case. I can't seem to find any other way of making it represent more than one character. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Any and all help in this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you want to loop through [all substrings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-all-substrings-of-given-string/) of `x` instead?

Comment: Maybe, can substrings be used to get specific bits of a string instead of all of them at once?

Comment: probably; which specific bits do you need? [please give me an example string and the set of substring you would want from it]

Comment: Simply put: I'd need to have x at different points to be equal to "S", "V1", "X", "V2" and "E", essentially chopping up the first string into usable code that can be converted via my program.

Comment: if you have an exact list of search possibilities, this might be a rare case for [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) .. however, if you want to simply make a program smaller, you may find very tangentially that using a complete compression algorithm like GZIP will handle ugly corner cases (for example, how would you handle two functions named `Vector1` and `Verify1`?) as it can handle arbitrary text without relying on a complex rules engine

Comment: In the full version I would make, I'd use dictionaries to hold all possibilities of the compressed text, with the full text being the key and the compressed text the value. Would it be possible to do this in conjunction with re.finditer()?

I'm trying to avoid using outside algorithms as it's against the rules of my project, though re.finditer() seems promising if I can use it with dictionaries! If it does work as I hope, how might I go about implementing it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Is there a better way to go about doing this?" I would like to be able to answer that, but for all that you wrote here, I still have *absolutely no idea what "this" is*. **What should happen** when you run the code? What does happen instead, and how is that different? Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the variable names in the compressed text always have only one letter, which is always at the beginning of the name, and that whitespaces can be ignored, you can use a function like:

```
def vnSplit(cText):
  #just in case:
  cText = str(cText) 
  if cText == '':
    return []
  #remove whitespace
  cText = ''.join(cText.split())

  varNames = []
  varName = cText[0]
  ctLen = len(cText)
  for i in range(1, ctLen):
    if cText[i].isalpha():
      varNames.append(varName)
      varName = '' 
    
    if i == ctLen - 1: #last char
        varNames.append(varName + cText[i])
    else: 
      varName = varName + cText[i]
  
  return varNames
```

then you can just loop through like `for x in vnSplit(Text):...`

Here are some sample outputs from the function:

```
("S V1XV2E") ---> ['S', 'V1', 'X', 'V2', 'E']
("SV2Exyz") ---> ['S', 'V2', 'E', 'x', 'y', 'z']
("abc324k_1") ---> ['a', 'b', 'c324', 'k_1']
```

[Printed using `for ct in cTexts: print(f'("{ct}") ---> {vnSplit(ct)}')`]

EDIT: if you want to go by a dictionary instead of the single-letter format, you could do something like:

```
def startVar(string, vDict):
  possVars = [v for v in vDict if string.startswith(v)]
  return possVars[0] if possVars else False

def vnExtract(cText, vDict): 
  cText = str(cText) #just in case

  #remove whitespace - but not on original
  ct = ''.join(cText.split())

  compressedVars = [] 
  extractedVars = []
  varName = ''
  varSuffix = ''
  while len(ct) > 0: 
    possVar = startVar(ct, vDict)
    if possVar:
      if varName != '': 
        compressedVars.append(varName + varSuffix)
        if varSuffix != '' and varSuffix[0].isalpha(): #OPTIONAL
          varSuffix = '_' + varSuffix #OPTIONAL
        extractedVars.append(vDict[varName] + varSuffix)
      varName = possVar
      varSuffix = ''
      ct = ct.replace(varName, '', 1)
    else:
      varSuffix = varSuffix + ct[0]
      ct = ct[1:]
    
    if ct == '' and varName in vDict:
      compressedVars.append(varName + varSuffix)
      if varSuffix != '' and varSuffix[0].isalpha(): #OPTIONAL
        varSuffix = '_' + varSuffix #OPTIONAL
      extractedVars.append(vDict[varName] + varSuffix)
    
  return {
      'compressed_text': cText,
      'compressed_vars': compressedVars,
      'extracted_vars': extractedVars
  }
```

It's called the same way, but dependent on `startVar()` and the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy1ad.png) is in a different format (easily changed by editing the `return`); but with this, the compression **must** adhere to the dictionary

Comment: Interesting... is there a way to allow for more than one letter per variable name in this function?

Comment: @Rambo then I might approach it in a different way - maybe with a reference list of possible variable "prefixes" to check through instead of the simpler `isalpha`, but the pattern can't be *too* confusing - like if both 'e', 'x' and 'ex' are possible prefixes, should 'ex2' return ['e', 'x2'] or ['ex2']? so, I wouldn't know what to do with overlapping patterns, but otherwise it's doable

Comment: I see what you're getting at, do you think I could integrate a dictionary in the place of `isalpha`, and if so may I ask how?

Comment: @Rambo I've added in an edit. The process is a bit different from the previous, but I think it can actually handle similar compressions such both "e" and "ex" **as long as** the longer/longest one ["ex"] comes first in the dictionary